# Juju - no route to host

Tags: juju, maas

I am using ubuntu server 14.04.2[image]
When I try to bootstrap maas, I get this error, how do I solve this ?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is 172.16.1.129 the IP of your MaaS server?  What it the IP and netmask of the bootstrap machine?  I hit a problem sort of like that, and doing a dpkg-reconfigure on maas region and cluster controllers fixed it.

Comment: The ip of my MaaS server is 172.16.1.128

Comment: Did this solve it?  The error you have above was with the MAAS API address as 172.16.1.129.

Comment: I did dpkg-reconfigure on maas region and cluster controller, and the ip was 172.16.1.128 don't know why is it saying 172.16.1.129 :s

Comment: Are you still getting the problem?

Comment: Not solved yet, but I created another VM and it's already bootstrapped!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before. The way I solve it is about the setting issue. Your internal (eth0) interfaces setting in the clusters page is not correct. In your case, the location is http://172.16.1.128/MAAS -> Clusters (on the top) -> choose your cluster -> Edit your Internal port at Interfaces -> Change your IP. 
Your IP should be 172.16.1.128. After I modifying the setting, I don't have this issue anymore.